# How to justify-content: center with Vuetify3

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vue-component, vuetify.js

I've my component at the top of the page but I want in in the middle.
[image: component at the top]

Like this:
[image: component in the middle]

This is my code:

```
<template>
  <v-container class="align-center" fill-height fluid>
    <v-row class="d-flex justify-center mb-6">
      <h1>Contador <v-icon>mdi-clock-outline</v-icon></h1>
    </v-row>
    <v-row class="d-flex justify-center mb-6">
      <h2>{{ count }}</h2>
    </v-row>
    <v-row class="d-flex justify-center mb-6">
      <v-btn @click="increment" class="mx-5" icon><v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon></v-btn>
      <v-btn @click="decrement" class="mx-5" icon><v-icon>mdi-minus</v-icon></v-btn>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

How can I put everything in the middle? using vuetify3 if it's possible, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `d-flex` class names to the container component and wrap `v-row`'s with `v-col` component:

```html
 <v-container class="align-center d-flex" fill-height fluid>
      <v-col>
        <v-row class="d-flex justify-center mb-6">
          <h1>Contador <v-icon>mdi-clock-outline</v-icon>
          </h1>
        </v-row>
        <v-row class="d-flex justify-center mb-6">
          <h2>{{ count }}</h2>
        </v-row>
        <v-row class="d-flex justify-center mb-6">
          <v-btn class="mx-5" icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn class="mx-5" icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-minus</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-row>
      </v-col>
    </v-container>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/KKRKaQY)

Comment: I'm not sure why is not working, now It looks like this:
https://imgur.com/a/S3r3y2n

Comment: Please check my edited answer

Comment: Thanks, I see is working in codepen, for some reason is not working in my pc, I'm using the beta of vuetify3+vite, maybe is some issue with that. But thanks anyway I gonna market as a correct answer cuz is working in codepen and you were very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `fill-height` doesn't exist in Vuetify 3, it's `class="h-100"`

Source: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/15733#issuecomment-1236087299